# What distribution does my data fall into?

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

Use X ray to hit the DNA, and DNA breaks (double strand breaks, DSBs). I'd assume the distribution of number of DSBs at a particular location on DNA is poisson? Or negative binomial?

How can I obtain the parameters (lambda, p, etc.) and how can I test if the data fall into what distribution?

The raw count histogram looks like the following:

[image]

The log(count) histogram looks like the following:

[image]

The distribution of the raw count:

```
1   209352
2   89918
3   32137
4   12316
5   5660
6   3060
7   1813
8   1102
9   781
10  535
11  364
12  331
```

.....

Comment: It is obviously not Poisson, as in the case of Poisson mean = variance.

Comment: Why do you think mean != variance here? Thanks.